# How to assert keyboard is closed?

Tags: cucumber, bdd, cucumber-java

I want to check my mobile keyboard is closed with an assertion.

```
public void keyboardIsClosed() {
    boolean isKeyboardShown = driver.isKeyboardShown();
    Assert.assertFalse("Keyboard is opened.",isKeyboardShown());
}
```

It doesn't accept last isKeyboardShown()in the code? How should i write?

I want to test whether or not the soft keyboard is shown with java

Comment: You use method syntax in assertion. Remove `()` so that you would have `Assert.assertFalse("Keyboard is opened.",isKeyboardShown);`

Answer (score 0):

Also

```
public void keyboardIsClosed() {
        Boolean isKeyboardShown;
        isKeyboardShown = driver.isKeyboardShown();
        Assert.assertFalse("Keyboard is opened.",isKeyboardShown==true);
    }
```

works